# Creating installation, Cant run application from programfiles if not admin

Tags: installation, admin, user-permissions

I made a small application and installation package for the application with installshield LE designed for Windows Xp/Windows7 32bit.
Everything is working ok but i have premission issues.

First of all, if user is not administrator then he cant install the installation package.
(In the Require administrative privileges i entered "No") - This issue is OS or installation package restriction ?

So.. I went to XP and logged in as normal user, i launched the installation and it elevated me to be admin. then I entered an admin password in order to continue the installation. afterwards everything went fine. now i cant start the application - only as administrator.

Why is that? how can i do that the user can run the application ?
it cant write the logs file (which my application writes) to the program files folder.. no premissions..

How can i handle this ? If a certain user installed the application i want him to be able to do anything with it. only the installation itself require admin log in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Program Files folder is a very special directory. Only admins are supposed to make changes to that. If your installation writes logs to Program Files, it is just wrong.

If you need a normal user to install and interact with your application, you should create an application and an installer suited for STANDARD USER. Such an installer will not write anything into Program Files.

Have a look at this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/30/778690.aspx